# How to add folder in google app script on form submit

Tags: javascript

```js
<script> 
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    M.AutoInit();
    M.updateTextFields();
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible.expandable');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elems, {accordion: false});

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed');
    var instances = M.Materialbox.init(elems, options);

  });
</script>
```

```css
<style>
h5{ color: white}
thead {color:white;}
tbody {color:black;}


table, th, td {
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
}
/* #search-results td:nth-child(1){background-color: red;} */
#search-results tr:hover {background-color: #dce775;}
.animation-area {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #8942a8, #ba382f);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.box-area {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box-area li {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 20s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(1) {
    left: 86%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(2) {
    left: 12%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(3) {
    left: 70%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    animation-delay: 5.5s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(4) {
    left: 42%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 15s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(5) {
    left: 65%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(6) {
    left: 15%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}


  /* body {
  display: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 60%;
  } */

  .img-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    display: absolute;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 0%;
    margin: center;
   
  }

  .collapsible{
    font-size:small;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top:-2%;
    left:80%;
  }
  .search{
    position: absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
  }
  .dropdown-content{
    position: absolute;
    top:-2%;
    left:60%;
  }

  .image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  
  }
  .image-hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
  }
  .image-hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
    <head>
      
      <?!= include('JavaScript') ?>
      <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>      
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
       <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      
      <base target="_top">
      
      <?!= include('Stylesheet') ?>         

      <script>
               
        function LoadFile(event)
        {
          var file = event.target.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.result);
            var fileData = e.target.result.substr(e.target.result.indexOf(",")+1);
            var mimeTypeStart = e.target.result.indexOf("data:") + 5;
            var mimeTypeEnd = e.target.result.indexOf(";");
            var mimeType = e.target.result.substr(mimeTypeStart, mimeTypeEnd - mimeTypeStart);
            var fileName = file.name;
            document.getElementById("fileData").value = fileData;
            document.getElementById("mimeType").value = mimeType;
            document.getElementById("fileName").value = fileName;
          };    
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }     

      </script>

      
    

    </head>

      <body>

        <div class="animation-area">
              <ul class="box-area">
       
            <div class="container">
              <div class="img-container" >
                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1EyH4NNI2xXvfHrDZcsO316728sulhJpn" class="logo" loading="eager">
                <h1><p style="color: #ffffff; margin: 0rem 0 0.68rem 0;">TVET <i>e</i>-Docs</p></h1>
              </div>

              <div >
                <h3 style="text-align: center; color: #ffffff;"><i> Welcome, </i><a href=https://mail.google.com/><?= sessionUser(); ?></a></h3>
              </div>

              <?var url = getUrl();?>
              
                <form style="margin: auto; width: 500px;" action="<?= url ?>" method="post" target="_top" onsubmit="myFunction()">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12">
                      <div class="input-field inline col s6">
                        <input style="width: 470px " id="studentName" name="studentName" type="text" class="validate" required>
                        <!-- <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i> -->
                        <label for="studentName">Lastname, First name, M.I </label>
                        <!-- <span class="helper-text" data-error="Please enter your full name" data-success="That's right"></span> -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                
                    <div class="file-field input-field">
                      <div class="btn" style="background-color: #0d47a1;">
                        <span>File</span>
                        
                        
                        <input type="file"id="file" name="file" onchange="LoadFile(event) " multiple required>
                        <input type="hidden" id="fileData" name="fileData" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="mimeType" name="mimeType" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="fileName" name="fileName" />
                      </div>

                      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input style="width:50%" class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload your file here">
                        <button style="position:absolute; left:400px; background-color: #0d47a1;" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                          <i class="material-icons right"></i>
                        </button>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                      
                    <p><span><center> <?= message ?> </center></span></p>
              
                </form>

                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
              
              </ul>
          
              
              <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            </div>

            
        </div>

        <script>
          //  PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form-inline');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
              
           
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
         
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<center><table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                           "<h5 scope='colspan=1'>STUDENT INFORMATION</h5>"+
                             "<tr>"+                             //Change table headings to match with the Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col=1'>LAST NAME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col=1'>FIRST NAME</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col=1'>M.I</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col=1'>COURSE</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col=1'>YEAR STARTED</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col=1'>YEAR ENDED</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col=1'>YEAR GRADUATED</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>" + dataArray[i][j] +"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
                  result += "</table></center>";
                    var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
                    div.innerHTML = result;
                  }else{
                    var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
                    //div.empty()
                    div.innerHTML = "No data found for"+ <?= search(); ?>;
            }
          }
      </script>

        <div class="search"> 
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
             
                  <!-- SEARCH FORM  -->
                  <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      
                      <label for="searchtext">Search for Student Data</label>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" placeholder="Enter student name" >
                    </div>
                    <button style="background-color: #0d47a1;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
                  </form>
                  <!-- SEARCH FORM ~ END  -->
               
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
             
                <!--  TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS  -->
                <div id="search-results" class="responsive-table" style="overflow-x:auto; width: 389px; height: 300px;">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                  
                </div>
                <!--  TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END  -->
                   
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        
       

        <div>
          <ul class="collapsible expandable">
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">assignment_ind</i>TVET REGISTRATION FORM</div>
              <div style="background: white;" class="collapsible-body"><span>
                  <div class="image-wrapper materialboxed">
                      <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1664W8zg82x5c3VwQuzdEnXyCI26QGRXs" download="regform">
                        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1MOW_GKgRC0UYGMOnX9EXItM5_R5n4b_J" alt="regform" width="75%" height="auto" class="image" alt="normal" />
                        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1zNu-XmECI6dkBXpEBde8EB7d2cpYQ-DM" alt="regform" width="75%" height="auto" class="image-hover" alt="hover" />
                      
                      </a><span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">assessment</i>COMPUTER SYSTEMS SERVICING NC II - ASSESSMENT FORM</div>
              <div style="background: white;" class="collapsible-body"><span>
                  <div class="image-wrapper materialboxed">
                      <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WNRJ1UicIis5Ye1QoeJnIObC-MxS7-aB" download="COMPUTER SYSTEMS SERVICING NC II">
                        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=14sk5xnAP5Rtc48Z52hpcBXFl8CQuk5Sd" alt="regform" width="75%" height="auto" class="image" alt="normal" />
                        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1vZKvz0VSWRdguvzI-xWkpB_uYd4EPbwx" alt="regform" width="75%" height="auto" class="image-hover" alt="hover" />
                      
                      </a><span>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">assessment</i>VISUAL GRAPHIC DESIGN NC III - ASSESSMENT FORM</div>
              <div style="background: white;" class="collapsible-body"><span>
                  <div class="image-wrapper materialboxed">
                      <a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1yLaYp66-DTK_dLC2fby1tG9VvbMf5KWe" download="VISUAL GRAPHIC DESIGN NC III">
                        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=14sk5xnAP5Rtc48Z52hpcBXFl8CQuk5Sd" alt="regform" width="75%" height="auto" class="image" alt="normal" />
                        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1vZKvz0VSWRdguvzI-xWkpB_uYd4EPbwx" alt="regform" width="75%" height="auto" class="image-hover" alt="hover" />
                      
                      </a><span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <footer class="page-footer" style="background: linear-gradient(to left, #8942a8, #ba382f);">
          
          <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
            © 2022 Mark Bryan Unico
            <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">Links</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
        
      </body>
</html>
```

I've got this project about file management where students will upload their files under my drive. first, they will have to log in their institutional account before they can access the web app, then they will provide name, upload their file then submit.

what I want to do is I have this folder in my drive where the uploaded files are saved and another folder where the logs are save via google sheet. I want it to create a folder (their own folder, named) inside the folder I created and append the files they uploaded.

what I have right now is..

Code.gs

```
    function doGet(e) {

  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser() //get the email address of the user running the script.
  Logger.log(userEmail)

  // Makes a request to fetch URL of the folder
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bzffkLsWYJKbu8NSk_zRGQn5XU1cwe73?usp=sharing')
  //Creates a new HtmlTemplate object from a file in the code editor.
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index') 
  htmlOutput.message = ''
  //Evaluates this template and returns an HtmlOutput object.
  return htmlOutput.evaluate().setTitle('TVET e-Docs').setFaviconUrl('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1-1VRBOF3O8JDEpK793UMO0lFBrqtVr9j&export=download&format=png');
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = ""
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext)
  }
  return result
}
 
//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId = '17utT0DHRUO7JYfbjvZJlRmf1J8GnTAILbCyRZiKYowY'
  var range = 'StudentsDB!A2:G'
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range).getValues()
  var ar = []
  
   
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f)
    }
  })
  Logger.log(ar)
  return ar
}



function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) 
  //sends to the folder destination with the given ID.
  var destination = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('UPLOADED FILES')
  var newFolder = destination.createFolder(e.parameter.studentName)
  
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameter.fileData)
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.fileName)
  newFolder.createFile(blob)

  //list reccord logs to sheet
  listRecord(e.parameter.studentName, e.parameter.fileName) 
  
  //Creates a new HtmlTemplate object from a file in the code editor.
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index') 
  //message when the process is successful
  
  htmlOutput.message = "File Sucessfully Uploaded."
  return htmlOutput.evaluate()
  }
  
function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder()
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
}
  

function listRecord(studentName, filename, userEmail)
{
  //get the email address of the user running the script.
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
  //fetch the url
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ifz1oM4CD_GuNv_uxoj0MKgembqjD-o6_2uhjZtY5F0/edit#gid=0')
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Records") //get the sheet name
  recordsSheet.appendRow([studentName, filename, new Date(), userEmail]) //append data
}

function getSelf() {
  
  var obj = People.People.getBatchGet({
    resourceNames: ['people/me'],
    personFields: 'names,emailAddresses'
  })
  var parsed = JSON.parse(obj.responses)
  var stringify = JSON.stringify(parsed.person.names,["displayName"])

  Logger.log(JSON.parse(stringify))
  return JSON.parse(stringify)
  
}


function userEmail(){
  var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser()
  Logger.log(userEmail)
  return userEmail
  
}


function getUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
 return url
}

function sessionUser(){
  var sesUsr = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername()
  Logger.log(sesUsr)
  return sesUsr 
}

function sendEmail(){
  
  // var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ifz1oM4CD_GuNv_uxoj0MKgembqjD-o6_2uhjZtY5F0/edit#gid=0'); //fetch the url
  // var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Records"); //get the sheet name
  // var data = recordsSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // var lr = recordsSheet.getLastRow();
  // //remove the header of the array
  // data.shift();
  // // console.log(data);

  // //loop over the rows in the spreadsheet
  // for(var i=2; i<=lr;i++) {
  //   var currMail = recordsSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
  //   var uploadDate = recordsSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
  //   var uploadedFile = recordsSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
  //   var usr = recordsSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();

  //     //write the email
  //   var subject ='TVET e-Docs: File Successfully Uploaded';
  //   let body = "Hello "+usr+","+" these are the file(s) you submitted"+"\n\n"+"Name of file: "+uploadedFile+"\n\n"+"Date: "+uploadDate;
  //   Logger.log(body);

  //     //send the email
  //     MailApp.sendEmail(currMail,subject,body);

      //mark as sent
      // var d = new Date();
      // var mailresp = recordsSheet.getRange(i,5).setValue(d);
      // Logger.log(mailresp);
    }
// }

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent()
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want it to create a folder (their own folder, named) inside the folder I created and append the files they uploaded.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: im sorry i didnt explain it well, what i want is after form submit, the name that they provided is the name of the folder inside the folder is just created in my drive. does that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot still understand your question. In your question, you have already had the specific folder, and you want to put the uploaded files in the specific folder. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes. correct.

i have this folder inside my drive that named "uploaded files". i have an html page that will ask for students name and his/her file to upload. then after he/she submitted the form, a folder will be created inside the upload files named with the students name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `i have this folder inside my drive that named "uploaded files". i have an html page that will ask for students name and his/her file to upload. then after he/she submitted the form, a folder will be created inside the upload files named with the students name.`, in this case, how about using `// var newFolder = destination.createFolder(studentName);` in your script?

Comment: I edited and uploaded my entire script here. please take a look